# OctoPack and OD Channels: How to create package version that can be piped into version channel?

Tags: octopus-deploy, octopack

We are using Octopus Deploy from TFS using the OctoPack package for convenience. We have a custom .nuspec file (generated on the fly) to pack up the deployment items and it works fine for the current mainline scenario.

Now I'm looking at setting up a pipeline for pre-release of next version in parallel to mainline and seems a channel would be perfect for the job.

However, channels are filtered on e.g. the format 2.0.0-alpha. OctoPack offers some control using the parameter OctoPackAppendToPackageId, but as the [documentation](https://github.com/OctopusDeploy/OctoPack) calls out that will append an idendifier like

```
/p:OctoPackAppendToPackageId=foo - Append the extra name to the package ID (e.g. for feature branch packages). MyApp.Foo.1.2.3.nupkg
```

However, channels are filtered on e.g. the format 2.0.0-alpha, i.e. with any extra suffix *after* the version number.

Is the conclusion that OctoPack is not really compatible with use of channels, or is there some other way I can either do channel filtering, alternately get OctoPack to produce a name that can be filtered?

Comment: Have you tried the `OctoPackAppendToVersion` parameter instead?

Comment: Ah. How embarrassing, it was there all the time... Thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OctoPackAppendToVersion` parameter instead.